# how to activate a function from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When clicking on an element, I am trying to call a function from another component. I import the function from a file, but it does not work. Can I call the function from another component in this way, or do I need to use a different method?

1.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={cn()}>
        <div onClick={onDownloadFile }>
          <UploadFile />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UploadForm, { onDownloadFile } from '1.js'
export default class extends Component {

  onDownloadFile = () => {
      ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UploadForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In `import UploadForm, {{onDownloadFile } from '2.js'` why it is not `1.js` and why the double bracket?

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors; it can't be what you're actually trying to run. Also, what are you _actually_ trying to do anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected a typo.I want to call a function on click

Comment: If 2.js isn't a child component of 1.js, the best option would be to create a hook for the download functionality. If it is a child component, you could pass the function to 2.js from 1.js as a prop.

Comment: This is a child element. Could you show by example?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, `UploadForm` is the default export from 1.js and child component in 2.js. You want to pass `onDownloadFile` as a callback prop to `UploadForm`.

1.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={cn()}>
        <div onClick={this.props.onDownloadFile }> // <-- access via props
          <UploadFile />
        </div>             
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UploadForm from '1.js';

export default class extends Component {
  onDownloadFile = () => {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UploadForm onDownloadFile={this.onDownloadFile} /> // <-- pass callback as prop
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```